# Finding the closest pair of points - How to implement split pairs inside recursive side pairs function calls

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, computational-geometry, divide-and-conquer

I'm trying to implement finding the closest pair of points algorithm using divide and conquer approach.

First some explanation, split pair (p1, p2) are te closest pair such that p1 is in the left side and p2 in the right. Side pair (p3, p4) are the closest pair such that p3 and p4 are in one side.

I've done the implementation that it returns the correct result but only if `closest_split_pairs` function is called separately(not inside `closest_side_pairs` function). So if I provide these points:

```
2,1
8,3
5,8
9,1
5,2
3,3
4,5
6,5
1,9
2,1.5
```

I get a result of `2,1` and `2,1.5`.

But if I called `closest_split_pair` inside `closest_side_pairs` (which I think it ought to be like that) .. I get a wrong result `3,3` and `4,5`. The problem is I don't know what must be done to integrate `closest_split_pairs` inside `closest_side_pairs`. Here's the code with `closest_split_pairs` called inside `closest_side_pairs` and the separate call is commented in `main` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <cfloat>
#include <cmath>

struct Point {
    Point(double x = 0, double y = 0) {
        x_coordinate = x;
        y_coordinate = y;
    }
    double x_coordinate;
    double y_coordinate;
    static bool sortByX(const Point &lhs, const Point &rhs) {
      return lhs.x_coordinate < rhs.x_coordinate;
    }
    static bool sortByY(const Point &lhs, const Point &rhs) {
      return lhs.y_coordinate < rhs.y_coordinate;
     }
};

using p_iterator = std::vector<Point>::iterator;

template<std::size_t SIZE>
using p_iterators_array = std::array<std::vector<Point>::iterator, SIZE>;

void initialize_points(std::vector<Point> &points) {
    double x, y;
    char c;
    std::ifstream infile("./points.txt");
    while((infile >> x >> c >> y) && (c == ',')) {
        points.push_back(Point(x, y));
    }
}

double calculate_distance(Point &p1, Point &p2) {
    return std::sqrt(std::pow(p1.x_coordinate - p2.x_coordinate, 2) + std::pow(p1.y_coordinate - p2.y_coordinate , 2));
}

template<typename T>
p_iterators_array<2> eucledian_closest(T &points, int size) {
    p_iterators_array<2> closest_arr;
    double closest_distance = DBL_MAX, distance = 0.0;

    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
      for(int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
        distance = calculate_distance(points[i], points[j]);
        if(distance < closest_distance ) {
          closest_distance = distance;
          closest_arr[0] = points + i;
          closest_arr[1] = points + j;
        }
      }
    }
    return closest_arr;
}

p_iterators_array<2> closest_split_pair(p_iterator points_iterator, p_iterators_array<2> &closest_side_pairs, std::size_t size) {
    std::vector<p_iterator> split_pairs;
    p_iterators_array<2> final_result;
    double closest_distance = DBL_MAX, distance = 0.0;

    p_iterator midpoint = points_iterator + (size/2);

    //filtering points to only points in sigma-2sigma rectangle
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      if(std::abs(points_iterator[i].x_coordinate - midpoint->x_coordinate) < calculate_distance(*(closest_side_pairs[0]), *(closest_side_pairs[1]))){
          split_pairs.push_back(points_iterator + i);
      }
    }

    //finding closest pair in split_pairs
    for (size_t i = 0; i < split_pairs.size() - 1; i++) {
      for (size_t j = i+1; (j < 7) && (j < split_pairs.size()) ; j++) {
        distance = calculate_distance(*(split_pairs[i]), *(split_pairs[j]));
        if(distance < closest_distance ) {
          closest_distance = distance;
          final_result[0] = split_pairs[i];
          final_result[1] = split_pairs[j];
        }
      }
    }

    //comparing split paris distance and side pairs distance
    if(calculate_distance(*(closest_side_pairs.front()), *(closest_side_pairs.back())) < calculate_distance(*(final_result.front()), *(final_result.back()))) {
      final_result = closest_side_pairs;
    }
    return final_result;
}

p_iterators_array<2> closest_side_pair(p_iterator points_iterator, p_iterator x_arr_iterator, p_iterator y_arr_iterator, std::size_t size) {
    std::size_t delimeter = size / 2 ;
    if(delimeter <= 3) {
      return eucledian_closest(points_iterator, delimeter);
    }
    p_iterators_array<2> closest_left, closest_right, result;

    closest_left = closest_side_pair(points_iterator, x_arr_iterator, y_arr_iterator, delimeter);
    closest_right = closest_side_pair(points_iterator + delimeter, x_arr_iterator + delimeter, y_arr_iterator + delimeter, delimeter);

    if(calculate_distance(*(closest_left.front()), *(closest_left.back())) < calculate_distance(*(closest_right.front()), *(closest_right.back()))) {
      result = closest_left;
    } else {
      result = closest_right;
    }
    return closest_split_pair(points_iterator, result, delimeter);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Point> points;
    initialize_points(points);

    std::vector<Point> x_p = points;
    std::vector<Point> y_p = points;
    std::sort(x_p.begin(), x_p.end(), Point::sortByX);
    std::sort(y_p.begin(), y_p.end(), Point::sortByY);

    p_iterators_array<2> closest_result = closest_side_pair(points.begin(), x_p.begin(), y_p.begin(), points.size());
    //Separate call of closest_split_pair
    //closest_result = closest_split_pair(points.begin(), closest_result, points.size());
    std::cout << "Closest pair are: " << std::endl;
    for(auto p: closest_result) {
        std::cout << p->x_coordinate << ", " << p->y_coordinate << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to match the recursive divide and conquer algorithm from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem  They pick one axis, and you are trying to do both and also work with the unsorted original data set? Also, I'm not sure if you correctly divide the array if there are an odd number of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a couple of bugs in the `closest_side_pair` routine.

When you call `eucledian_closest` routine, the length of vector passed to that function is `delimiter` whereas that should be `size`. Similarly, when you call `closest_split_pair`, the length of vector passed is `delimiter`. That should be `size`.

Currently what `closest_split_pair` does is, it assumes that midpoint is at `points_iterator + delimiter/2` you want that to be at `points_iterator + size/2`. This will look confusing, but just replace 'delimiter' with 'size' in `closest-side_pair`, your code must work.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I didn't notice it at all. But what about `eucledian_closest` why should it be `size` not `delimeter` ?

Comment: @RafaelAdel: When not splitting, all of the remaining points must be considered.